# ListView is null despite setting the content view before

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to get a reference to my ListView as follow:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mainListView);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
        }
    });
```

However, while debugging it, the ListView seems to be null (so is the savedInstanceState, but thats something else)
Here is the very basic xml of my ListView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView android:id="@+id/mainListView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
</ListView>
```

edit:
content of activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: how did you know that the listview is null ?

Comment: by debugging it - The ref is null, it's not the case for "toolbar", "fab", etc

Comment: post `activity_main.xml`

Comment: edit: content of activity_main.xml

Comment: why u have to make a different layout for listview? fyi **findViewById** only search for id inside the content view which is on your case **setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently your `ListView` is itself a separate layout file (which is not a part of `activity_main`) so you need to `include` your `ListView` layout in your `activity_main.xml` (just like `app_bar_main`) or optionally you can directly add `ListView` in `actvity_main`

**Note**: change height of `appbar` to `wrap_content` and also use `match_parent` instead of `fill_parent`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/name_of_your_listView_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```